# Automatically fill in ssh identity file password?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

When I made my ssh key I added a password to the key. Right now I'm trying to write a script that will run some ssh and rsync commands. Unfortunately, since I have the password on my rsa key it prompts for the password every single time. Is there a way that I can prompt the user for the key passphrase once then redirect it into the ssh command?

** this is not an ssh user password. this is the passphrase for the key **

Comment: Why not load it into the agent?

Comment: do you have any leads on how I would do that?

Comment: You can also remove the passphrase from that key, but that is a solution that exists, but it's not recommended - https://stackoverflow.com/q/112396/2231796 - Stick with the answer given on your question(use a ssh agent) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ssh key agent. The command to launch the agent is:

```
ssh-agent
```

Then you'll have to add your key to the agent. To add the default key (~/.ssh/id_rsa) you would use this command:

```
ssh-add
```

You'll have to enter your password once in order to add your key.

You might also want to check out this ServerFault post for more information:

- [Running ssh-agent from a shell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/547923/running-ssh-agent-from-a-shell-script)

Maybe the cleanest solution proposed there was to add an ssh-agent shebang to your script, e.g.:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/ssh-agent bash

ssh-add /path/to/ssh-key
ssh root@remotehost "remote commands"
```

There are also a lot of gotchas associated with using the ssh agent, so you might want to read some articles about general usage advice, e.g.:

- [The pitfalls of using ssh-agent, or how to use an agent safely](http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents)

Comment: You need to do `eval $(ssh-agent)` because `ssh-agent` outputs some environment variables (e.g. SSH_AUTH_SOCK, SSH_AGENT_PID) that need to be exported for `ssh-add` and other commands to work.